# sql how add count

Tags: mysql, sql

Query to auto increment `"treasureKeys"`. Similar to below script.

sql:

```
INSERT INTO UltraCosmeticsData (uuid, username, treasureKeys) 
VALUES ('{custom_uuid}', '{user}', '3');
```

Comment: You'll need to set it up from your app.

Comment: For autoincrement just setup your field on the `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `tablename` SET `tablename1` = `tablename1` + 3 WHERE tablename2 LIKE "tablename2";